# How to get multiple comparisons without using relevel() for a clmm ordinary model?

Tags: r, comparison, logistic-regression, summary, tukey

I've been dealing with a dataset that has levels with many independent variables. I have an ordinal dependent variable, and 4 others independent variables (or fixed effects), with more than one level each (it's a 2x3x3x4 study). I runned a clmm model using the package Ordinal (adding two random effects), and the model took one level from each independent variable as reference and made its comparisons. I was wondering how could I compare those that were not taken.

Let me simplify that: Imagine that I have an independent variable with 3 levels (A, B, and C). My model will take one of them as a reference level (let's say A), and will show me the differences between A and B, and between A and C. But how could I have the difference between B and C? I was trying to use the relevel() function, making my model take different levels as references. But when you have such a big model (like 2x3x3x4), it's quite tricky (and tiring) to relevel over and over until you have all the comparisons you need.

I also tried to run a post-hoc pairwise HSD Tukey analysis, but the significance values there were different from my models, and I learned now that a Tukey analysis is different from the analysis the model do and I honestly don't want to go into that now.

I just want to see comparisons between levels that are not taken as references levels without having to relevel over and over again.

I've tried to relevel over and over, but it's really tiring.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `emmeans` package?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `MASS::polr`
For a detailed description look [at this nice website](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/)

Comment: @BenBolker I've tried to use emmeans but with tukey adjust, and it's not exactly what I want since the comparison values were different from the original model. Do you know a function in this package I could use to get comparisons without adjusting them as tukey does?